# Onclick Not Working on a Button

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a JSFiddle I'm making, and the onclick event is not firing. It's probably just something simple that I'm missing, can anyone help?

JavaScript:

```
var out = document.getElementById("currentOut");
var oldout = document.getElementById("output");
var input = document.getElementById("PXInput");
var cc = "";

    function submit(){
        alert();
        cc = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    alert(cc);
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="PXInput"></textarea>
<br/>
<button id="submitLine" type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<div id="output">
    <span id="currentOut"></span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cwoe1s0u/4/

Comment: You need top move your script before the markup, e.g. to the document head -http://fiddle.jshell.net/cwoe1s0u/5/

Comment: Thanks guys! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change javascript Load Type to "No Wrap - in body".